# External KeyBoard BackLight is Not Working On Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, backlight

Hello Guys I bought a new keyboard for my HP laptop and the backlight is not working

I tried :

```
xset led
```

and all commands with " xset " like set -l led or bla bla

**so the only way was :**

```
light -L
```

and then

```
❯ sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/input7::scrolllock/brightness'
```

so i think about way to make it more ez by put it in command shortcut .

first problem was "sudo" Acsess so I solve it by :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "$(logname) ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$(logname)' && sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/$(logname)
```

secound problem : input change evrey time!

sometimes works with input 7 and sometime with 3 , and offen with 6 !

how i can solve it to make an easy shortcut to light the keyboar??

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, nor if you're actually using Xorg (ie. `xset` is an Xorg command) or Wayland, but your unstated Ubuntu product & release details would be a start.